# Why is there a need to verify if the equation is exact?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have read that if I'm given a equation

$$eqn  \ 1:Mdx \ + \ Ndy \ = 0$$

The equation is exact if

$$eqn \ 2:M_y=N_x$$

And that if the equation is really exact, we then proceed to find the solution such that

$$eqn \ 3:u(x,y) = \int M dx=C$$
Where C is an arbitrary constant

While I do understand that verifying if the eqn is exact will help save time in determining whether if there is a solution, but is it possible to just jump straight into eqn 3 and solve and conclude that the eqn is not exact if $\int Mdx \neq \int Ndy$?

Comment: Are you asking if we can still get a solution using eqn 3 of the form $u(x,y) = C$, even if the equation is not exact (i.e. even if $M_y \ne N_x$)?

Comment: Will it save time to walk across a street without first looking out for cars?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth , something along that line. As in, we always verify the equation is exact if $M_y=N_x$, but is there such an equation that exist such that $u(x,y)=\int M dx=\int N dy$ but the given eqn is not exact?

Comment: Well the whole reason we can look for a solution using eqn 3 (with $u_x = M$ and $u_y = N$) is due to the exactness of the ODE.

Comment: do you know what is the meaning of *exact* differential of a *function* of two variables ?

Comment: Well the whole reason we can get a solution of the form $u(x,y) = C$ (with $u_x = M$ and $u_y = N$) is due to the exactness of the ODE. Try searching online or in your notes (if you have notes) for a derivation of the method you are using to solve exact equations.

Comment: damn good question, i used to wonder the same

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question in the comments is "no".  If $u = \int M = \int N$ then the equation is exact.

If you proceed to try to solve an un-exact equation using the exact method, it will fail.  You will end up with function of one variable equal to a function of two variables and you'll be stuck there.  You might save time by skipping the check for exactness, but you also end up with no solution.

A reason to do the check anyway, is that if the equation fails to be exact, there are tests for integrating factors which are based on $M_y-N_x.$  So if you skip the check and then the method fails, your next step is to compute $M_y$ and $N_x$ anyway.

So you save time in the end by doing the check.